# Can a product support recurring and not recurring payment at the same time?

Tags: 8, commerce, payment-gateways

So if for some product variant I check option "Allow subscriptions" all product variants of that products can be bought only in recurring way? Is that true?

I mean, I can not have one product and one set of variations that can be purchased "normal" way (by paying whole price during checkout process) and other set of variations support subscriptions and recurring payment? Is that right?

If I want to support both ways of paying (recurring and "normal") for one product I actually have to create 2 separate products? Correct?

Asking because when I edit product variation fields "Subsription type" and "Billing schedule" are both mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [`this`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/commerce-iats/how-to-setup-recurring-payments) page, you can see that what comes out of the box is that you create a seperate product variation for the recurring products and then create seperate products.

Instructions from the docs:

> 1. Download and install the Commerce Recurring Framework and Advanced queue Drupal modules.
>
>    1. Create a variation for the recurring products
>    2. Go to admin/commerce/config/product-variation-types
> 2. Add a product variation type with the “Allow subscriptions” trait
> 3. Create a product type for recurring products
>
>    1. Go to admin/commerce/config/product-types
>    2. Add a product type that uses the previously-created product variation
> 4. Create one or more billing schedules. The billing schedules will become options when configuring your product.
>
>    1. Go to admin/commerce/config/billing-schedules
>    2. Create a new billing schedule with the desired options
>
>       1. Fixed (specific day of month) or rolling (from creation date)
>       2. Dunning options to remind users for expiring credit cards
> 5. Create a product
>
>    1. Use the previously-created product type, with the recurring variation
>    2. Use the desired billing schedule

A possible solution would be to create a custom block that switches between the two products on the product page.

If you want to fetch data from the recurring product on the normal product, you might want to create a reference field to the recurring product on the normal product.